# How to use selenium storeValue in another window

Tags: selenium, testcase

I need to create a following testcase in selenium and seek help 
1.Open a site http://foo.bar in browser 
2. log to site 
3. select some content and store in a variable (this can be done through selenium storeValue)
4. Open another site http://baz.bar
5. login into site
6. use the stored content to search in that site

My question is which selenium command will correspond to step 6.

I have racked my brain going through selenium reference and am failing to find this particular command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code may help you.

```
selenium.open("http://air.irctc.co.in/");
selenium.waitForPageToLoad("3000");
String content= selenium.getText("link=www.irctc.co.in");
//System.out.println(cc);
selenium.open("http://www.google.com");
selenium.waitForPageToLoad("3000");
selenium.type("q",content);
selenium.click("btnG");
selenium.waitForPageToLoad("3000");
```

In the above code I am storing the link in a content variable after using Google Search.

Comment: Thanks Lakshamanan, Let me say this was the first time I was using selenium. Your answer pointed me to the java based scripts of selenium . Thanks